# How to add onclick effect in a html link (<a>) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm sitting here with a school project, I've done a bunch og html and css, now it's time for the Javascript to apply. 
My question is, how to add an onclick effect to a link? 
this is what I have already, I can't seem to figures this function out, yet.

```
 <li><a id="male" onclick=")" href="#male">Male</a></li>
```

and the script that didn't work:

```
<script> 
    function maleFunction(el) {
    document.getElementById(male).style.border = "1px solid black";
    }

</script>
```

trying to add a border when I click the link element, Male, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you think `onclick=")"` would actually do?

Answer (score 4):

Your content of `onclick` is wrong. It should be:

```
 <li><a id="male" onclick="maleFunction(this)" href="#male">Male</a></li>
```

And give a `return false;` at the end of the function. And you need to change the `male` to el, as you are already referring to it.

```
function maleFunction(el) {
    el.style.border = "1px solid black";
    return false;
}
```

It is always better to use event delegation and event handler for these cases. In your case, it should be this way:

```
<li><a id="male" href="#male">Male</a></li>
```

Already you have an `id`. So it is easy to get it this way:

```
document.querySelector("male");
```

Once you have got the element, just add the event handler:

```
document.querySelector("male").onclick = function () {
    // Note the above line, it is an anonymous function without a name.
    // You can use "this" to refer the current object.
    this.style.border = "1px solid black";
}
```

It is not a good idea to have inline styles. So, use something like this in your CSS:

```css
.selected {border: 1px solid black;}
```

And now add the class to the particular element:

```
document.querySelector("male").onclick = function () {
    // Note the above line, it is an anonymous function without a name.
    // You can use "this" to refer the current object.
    this.classList.add("selected");
}
```